# VueJs Multiple component in list item takes a huge loading time

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am working on VueJS language. In that I am facing a huge performance issue.

I have one page which displaying listing of items. Now each list items have a multiple components like shown in attached image.

I have also put pagination so at a time only 10 list items will be displayed still when it loads first time it took around 1 minute to bind all DOM elements.

API gives response in miliseconds.

This is one item of list. there will be 10 items at a time

[image: This is one item of list.. so like this there will be 10 items at a time]

Comment: Without including the code for your components, your templates and some sample data it is nearly impossible to even guess what could be causing the issue.

Comment: @PatrickSteele can you let me know if is there any way to show loader till vue is binding data to html...currently what happening is service returned data fast till then loader runs but after that it took around 1 minute to bind data and then there loader stucks on screen